# How to wrap text of an entire column in xlsxwriter

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

Hi i would like to wrap a text of an entire column specifically as it is too long. How do i achieve that.

This is the output that I get:
[image]

This is the code which i have wrote:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([config[s] for s in config.sections()])
df2 = df2[["control_name", "rationale"]]

print(df2)
# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object. Note that we turn off
# the default header and skip one row to allow us to insert a user defined
# header.
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='For PDF', startrow=0, index=False, header=False)

df2.columns = ["Control Name", "Rationale"]

# Create xlsxwriter workbook object .
workbook = writer.book
# Create xlsxwriter worksheet object
worksheet = writer.sheets['For PDF']

text_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap' : True})

# Add a header format.
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'text_wrap': True,
    'valign': 'center',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'border': 1})

# Write the column headers with the defined spacing format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df2.columns.values):
     worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

for column in df2:
    column_width = max(df2[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column)+1)
    col_idx = df2.columns.get_loc(column)
    writer.sheets['For PDF'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)

 writer.save()
```

This is the output that i want to achieve:
[image]

Please help to achieve both the desired columns as shown above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

To set the text wrap format for the entire column you need to add the format object to a `set_column()` call. Something like this:

```py
writer.sheets['For PDF'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width, text_format)
```

Set the `column_width` to None if you don't want to specify the column width. Also, your current code seems to be auto fitting the column widths. Having very wide columns, to the width of the string, will mean that the text won't/won't need to wrap.

Update: added example.

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Control name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
                    'Rationale': [
                        'some long sentence ' * 4,
                        'some longer sentence ' * 6,
                        'hello ' * 10]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_wrap.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='For PDF')


# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['For PDF']

# Add a format.
text_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap' : True})

# Resize columns for clarity and add formatting to column C.
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 20)
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 20, text_format)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How do i achieve that?
The setting column_width=None does not help. Based from my codes how am i able to wrap the column without autofitting the column?

Comment: Did you add the text wrap format to the `set_column()` call?

Comment: yes i did, the excel sheet remains the same. no changes was made. Even tried removing the column_width variable or setting the column_width=None

Comment: I've added a complete example to demonstrate how this works. You can adapt it to your code.

Comment: Thanks it works. Apparently,  the wrap text is not functioning in linux enviroment. However, when i shift the file and even the codes over to windows the format conditioning works